# Issue with TFT lcd screen speed

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, openwrt, lcd

I am using TFT LCD screen (**ILI9163c** - 160*128). It is connected with **athros** **AR9331** module with spi. Athros AR9331 is running with **OpenWRT** linux distribution. So, I am driving my LCD with **spidev0.1**. While filling screen or writing any string on LCD, it is taking too much time to print. So, what can i do to get sufficient printing speed.

Thanks.

This is the function i'm using to write data on spi pin using spidev...

```
void spi_transactor(unsigned char *write_data, int mode,int size)
{
    int ret;
    struct spi_ioc_transfer xfer[4];

    unsigned char *init_reg;
    init_reg  = (unsigned char*) malloc(size);
    memcpy(init_reg,write_data,size);

    if (mode)
    {
        gpio_set_value(_rs, 1);    // DATA
    }
    else
    {
        gpio_set_value(_rs, 0);    // COMMAND
    }

    memset(xfer, 0, sizeof xfer);

    xfer[0].bits_per_word = 8;
    xfer[0].tx_buf = (unsigned long)init_reg;
    xfer[0].rx_buf = 0;               //( unsigned long ) &buf_rx[0];
    xfer[0].len = size;               //wlength + rlength;
    xfer[0].delay_usecs = 0;
    xfer[0].speed_hz = speedx;       // 8MHZ
    //xfer[0].speed_hz = 160000000;    // 40MHZ
    ret = ioctl(spi_fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &xfer);

    gpio_set_value(_rs, 1);
}
```

Comment: Hard to say in general. I assume, that you have tuned speedx to the maximum. Do you try to pack as much data as possible into a single request? Do you try to use optimal display commands for what you want to display?

Comment: ya... thats true. And i'm trying to pack as much data as possible into a single request because i need to print the whole image of 160*128 array. so i break this array in some chunks and than transfer all this chunks one by one.

Comment: And what is the propblem to add *fbtft* driver into a distribution and use it as a normal console or tty window?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main performance issue here is that you make a hard copy of the data to send on the heap, every time the function is called. You also set up the communication parameters from scratch each time, even though they are always the same. To make things worse, the function has a massive bug: it leaks memory as if there's no tomorrow.

The hard copies aren't really necessary *unless* the SPI communication takes too much time for the program to sit and busy-wait on it to finish (rather likely). What you can do in that case is this:

- Outsource the whole SPI business to a separate thread.
- Create a work queue for the thread, using your favourite ADT for such. It should be a thread-safe FIFO.
- Data is copied into the ADT as hard copies, by the caller.
- The thread picks one chunk of work from the ADT and transmits it from there, without making yet another hard copy.
- The thread waits for the SPI communcation to finish, then makes sure that the ADT deletes the data, before grabbing the next one. For hard real-time requirements, you can have the thread prepare the next message in advance while waiting for the previous one.
- The communication parameters "xfer" are set up *once* by the thread, it just changes the data destination address from case to case.

Comment: Thank you... @Lundin. I will try to modify my code as you advice.  But while printing a string on LCD, this function will print data pixel by pixel for every characters. so,that time it is very slow. What i can do in that scenario.

Comment: @Logan859 If there's some way for you to wait effectively for the SPI task to finish, through the API, then the thread should use that and sleep until SPI is done. If that isn't available, then you'll just have to busy-wait. As for how slow/fast the SPI is, that depends mostly on the baudrate. Btw you should also look if DMA is available - it would solve the whole problem much more elegantly.